# Will a bluetooth keyboard work with Bitlocker?

Tags: windows-10, boot, keyboard, bluetooth, bitlocker

I would like to purchase a Bluetooth keyboard, but I am concerned it will not work with my setup.

I am running Windows 10 with a USB Bluetooth device to get Bluetooth.The USB Bluetooth device receives all Bluetooth connections. I also have BitLocker running at startup which requires a password for the boot to continue.

Would my computer be able to detect and use the Bluetooth keyboard at boot time to enter the BitLocker password?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a Bluetooth keyboard won't work for BitLocker prompt. Bluetooth is not initialized until Windows is up and running. BitLocker prompt is way before that.

However, a wireless keyboard that uses a dongle (e.g. most of Logitech's offer) will work because their USB dongle simulates USB HID which is generally supported during boot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, depending on the bluetooth dongle/hardware in your PC/laptop.

Some bluetooth dongles/hardware support "HID proxy" which would enable them to be used pre-boot in the BIOS or at the BitLocker PIN entry screen.