# Bitlocker Password Entry Screen does not work with specific brands of USB Keyboards

Tags: windows, keyboard, bitlocker

My laptop runs Windows 11 and full-disk encryption via Bitlocker. When starting the computer, the blue Bitlocker Password Prompt screen appears.

When I use the Laptop keyboard or a Lenovo USB keyboard, I can enter the password just fine.

However, when using a keyboard model "Fnatic miniSTREAK", the input is completely wrong.

For example, when I type "asdf", it would show up as "m77". "A" would register as "m7", "S" as "7", and "D" and "F" would be completely ignored.

How can I make this keyboard work with Bitlocker?

Comment: Is this a Bluetooth keyboard ? ([link](https://superuser.com/questions/1170442/will-a-bluetooth-keyboard-work-with-bitlocker)). Try to disable Fast boot.

Comment: It is a normal USB keyboard. Fast boot doesn't make a difference.